# How to make git properly diff a replaced file

Tags: git

When diffing two revisions, how can I make git properly follow a history where a file was replaced?

Here is an example. I create a file [commit], move it [commit], then create another file with the same name [commit].

```
echo "original" > test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
mv test.txt test2.txt
git add --all .
git commit -m "Rename"
echo "replace" > test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Replace"
```

When diffing between `HEAD^^` and `HEAD`, how can I make git realize that test.txt is really a brand new file? The best command I could find was something like `git diff -M100% -C100% HEAD^^` but that doesn't produce the results I am looking for.

```
git diff -M100% -C100% HEAD^^
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 4b48dee..6e8b374 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-original
+replace
diff --git a/test.txt b/test2.txt
similarity index 100%
copy from test.txt
copy to test2.txt
```

Is there a better command to get this expected output?

```
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 4b48dee..6e8b374 100644
--- /dev/null
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+replace
diff --git a/test.txt b/test2.txt
similarity index 100%
copy from test.txt
copy to test2.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't.  Git always does heuristic rename detection and, at least currently, regardless of any ancestry path computable from the commit DAG, when you give `git diff` two commits it simply compares them directly.  In this case it is comparing `HEAD^^` vs `HEAD` and both have a `test.txt` and the second has a `test2.txt`, so its heuristics say that while `test2.txt` may or may not be a copy of some other file, `test.txt` is not renamed.

(When comparing `HEAD^^` vs `HEAD^`, there is no `test.txt` in `HEAD^`, so its rename detection code will see if perhaps `test2.txt` matches the previous `test.txt`.  Hence if it scanned through the ancestry path leading from `HEAD^^` through `HEAD^` to `HEAD`, its current heuristics *would* detect the rename.  But it doesn't do that.  Or, if Git had the option to do a computationally-expensive O(n<sup>2</sup>) comparison between all files, rather than just those that have no counterparts on either "side" of the diff, that could also discover the rename as well; but again, it doesn't.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the direct and through answer! It makes me wonder if someone has made a script to either walk the history or do a costly comparison.

Comment: Michael Haggerty wrote `git-imerge` as a script that can do iterative merge or rebase, which handles the history walking when doing these operations.  It has its own issues though.  See http://softwareswirl.blogspot.com/2013/05/git-imerge-practical-introduction.html